# Jooq dsl for batch insert of maps, arrays and so forth

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Im hoping to use jooq dsl to do batch inserts to postgres. I know it's possible but Im having issues getting the data formatted properly.

```
dslContext.loadInto(table).loadJSON(json-data).fields(...).execute();
```

is where Im starting from. The tricky part seems to be getting Map<String, String> into a jsonb column.

I have the data formatted according to [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-sources/importing-source-json/) description and jooq seems to be ok with it.. until the map/json-in-json shows up.

Another json-array column still needs to be dealt with too.

Questions:

1. is this a reasonable approach?
2. if not - what would you recommend instead?

Error(s) Im seeing:

```
ERROR: column "changes_to" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

---

Edit:

```
    try (DSLContext context = DSL.using(pgClient.getDataSource(), SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)) {
        context.loadInto(table(RECORD_TABLE))
                .loadJSON(jsonData)
                .fields(field(name(RECORD_ID_COLUMN)),
                        field(name(OTHER_ID_COLUMN)),
                        field(name(CHANGES_TO_COLUMN)),
                        field(name(TYPE_COLUMN)),
                        IDS_FIELD)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

with json data:

```
{"fields":[{"name":"rec_id","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"other_id","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"changes_to","type":"jsonb"},{"name":"en_type","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"ids","type":"BIGINT[]"}],"records":[["recid","crmid","{\"key0\":\"val0\"}","ent type",[10,11,12]],["recid2","crmid2","{\"key0\":\"val0\"}","ent type2",[10,11,12]]]}
```

The problem(s) being how to format the 'changes_to' and 'ids' columns.

Comment: Can you show a bit more code of what you've ried? See this useful page here, which explains what kinds of information we might be looking for, to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a certain price to pay if you're not using [jOOQ's code generator (and you should!)](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/) jOOQ doesn't know what of data type your columns are if you create a `field(name("..."))`, so it won't be able to bind your values correctly. Granted, the `Loader` API could read the JSON header information, but it currently doesn't.

Instead, why not just either:

- Provide explicit type information to your column references, like `field(name(CHANGES_TO_COLUMN), SQLDataType.JSONB)`
- Much better: use the code generator, in case of which you already have all the type information associated with your `Field` expression.

Comment: To use SQLDataType.JSONB I have to move to jooq v3.16 (currently 3.11) - but this gives me an error saying that DSLContext doesn't support AutoCloseable anymore.. if I can't figure this out I'll open a new question.

Comment: @acme-j: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518685/521799 and https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10512